# How to include a module to a haskell source code file

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

What is the syntax to include a module in a Haskell source code file? I am writing

```
import Data.Maybe
```

at the top of my source code file however it gives the error

```
error: parse error on input `import'
```

Comment: You need to write this at the top of the file. After the `module ... where` if you define a module name.

Comment: Oh Alright! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because you imported the module at the wrong place in the file. The `import` statements should be written at the top of the file, immediately after a `module` statement (if you use one). You thus should *not* import a module after you defined one (or more) types, functions, etc.

A file thus looks like:

```
-- module name (optional)
module MyModuleName where

-- import statements
import Data.Maybe
-- ⋮

-- functions, types, typeclasses, etc.
-- ⋮
```